Flutter prevent GridView.builder from rebuilding its children
I have a list of GridView.builder items that when I scroll up and down, are rebuilding again and again, how can I prevent that? It is affecting my user experience.
this is my GridView:
GridView.builder(
  itemCount: images.length,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    childAspectRatio: 60 / 100,
    crossAxisSpacing: 14,
    mainAxisSpacing: 14,
  ),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ImageGridItem(
      imageUrl: images[index],
      isSelected:
          backgroundImageProvider.currentImageUrl == images[index]
              ? true
              : false,
      isUnlocked: unlockedImages.contains(images[index]),
      index: index,
    );
  },
);

and this is my ImageGridItem widget:
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:quotes_app/components/bottom_sheet_widget.dart';
import 'package:quotes_app/providers/background_image_provider.dart';
import 'package:quotes_app/screens/tabs_screen.dart';

class ImageGridItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImageGridItem({
    super.key,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.isSelected,
    required this.isUnlocked,
    required this.index,
  });

  final String imageUrl;
  final bool isSelected;
  final bool isUnlocked;
  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        if (isSelected) return;

        if (isUnlocked) {
          final backgroundImageProvider =
              Provider.of<BackgroundImageProvider>(context, listen: false);

          await backgroundImageProvider.toggleImage(imageUrl);
        }

        if (!isUnlocked) {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: TabsScreen.scaffoldKey.currentContext!,
            builder: (ctx) {
              return BottomSheetWidget(
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                index: index,
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        decoration: isSelected
            ? BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.green.shade900, width: 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
              )
            : null,
        child: Container(
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, progress) {
                  final downloaded = progress.downloaded.toDouble();
                  final total = progress.totalSize?.toDouble() ?? 1.0;
                  final percentage = (downloaded / total) * 100;

                  return Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: double.infinity,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                      ),
                      if (percentage.toStringAsFixed(0) != '0')
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            CircularProgressIndicator(
                              value: downloaded / total,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              strokeWidth: 2,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 8),
                            Text(
                              '${percentage.toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
                fadeInDuration:
                    Duration(milliseconds: 100), // Reduce fade-in duration
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Center(
                  child: Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.red),
                ),
              ),
              if (!isUnlocked)
                Positioned(
                  top: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(128, 0, 0, 0),
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16)),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.lock,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I tried to use statefulwidget instead of statelesswidget in my ImageGridItem widget but it doesn't work. I passed a ValueKey to each item in the GridView.builder but it didn't work. I used AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin but it didn't work again. also, I used GridView instead of GridView.builder but it didn't work again.
if you have any solution I appreciate it.
